# What are good candidates for a fixed, externally accessible database for Qt/C++?

Tags: database, c++, qt

I'm developing an app in Qt/C++ which has a particular dialog that needs some sort of database.

The dialog will have three widgets: a list of items on the left, a textual description field at the middle and an optional image on the right.

There is an image and a description for each of the item on the list, while the list is related to a particular item chosen in a combo box. So the user selects the item in the combo box, its correspondent list appears and the user goes on to click in each item to see its description and image.

I need to store all this info outside the source code (the image being only the file path), but I'm not sure which way would be the best. SQL databases doesn't seem to be for such "fixed usage" and a XML is supposed to only transfer data between applications. What other options do I have that are nice to be used with Qt/C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like the QSQLITE database driver from [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html).

Data is stored in compact files. No typical database setup required.

The Sqlite project provides the command line tool `sqlite3` for conveniently manipulating the data through standard SQL statements.